# Unicode issue: How to convert â€™ to ’ in the response from HttpClient?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, apache-httpclient-4.x, utf-16

The `String s` and `byte[] b` in the code below contain different representations of roughly the same thing.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Utf8Test {

    @Test
    public void test() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String s = "â€™";
        byte[] b = new byte[] { (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0x80, (byte) 0x99 };

        System.out.println(s); // prints â€™

        String t = new String(b, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(t); // prints ’

        String u = new String(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(u); // prints ???

        byte[] b2 = new byte[s.length()];
        for(int i=0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            b2[i] = (byte) (s.charAt(i) & 0xFF);
        }
        String v = new String(b2, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(v); // prints ?"

        Assert.assertEquals(s,v); // FAIL
    }

}
```

How can I convert `String s` to the same value as `String t`?

I have already tried the code resulting in `String u` and `String v`, and the result is indicated in the comments.

**XY Problem**
This is actually an XY Problem. The `String s` is being returned in the `HttpEntity` of an `HttpClient` call. All I want is the properly decoded response. The above is far easier to reproduce than a whole HTTP stack so let's solve that instead.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the HttpEntity - is it request or response? And which method - specifically, returns that string?

Comment: I use the `HttpEntity` (indirectly via a Spring Rest Template) to read the response from a RESTful service. It's the `getBody()` method. I've chased this in a debugger and found the issue is present all the way down in the `InputStream` at the lowest levels of the HTTP connection. There might be a double-enconding at the web service, which I do not maintain.

Comment: It sounds like the web services or web page you're using is not correctly communicating the character set used, so the default encoding is used.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, but I don't understand why, and I worry it may be platform-dependent:

```
byte[] d = s.getBytes("cp1252"); 
String w = new String(d, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(w); // prints ’
```

Comment: The problem with solving it this way is that the `HttpClient` / `HttpEntity` transforms the received byte stream into a string (using an unspecified encoding, but it could by the platform default encoding), and then you try convert it back into a byte array just to transform it into a string again (using the `UTF-8` encoding). A better way would be to tell `HttpClient` / `HttpEntity` to use the `UTF-8` encoding in the first place!